# CSS Slide Show not working for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am implementing a CSS slide show on my site. I used this CodePen as a guide: http://codepen.io/antoniskamamis/pen/hjBrE

I first experienced an issue with the Slide Show not working correctly in Safari. I was able to address that issue by adding animation-delay properties that are for all browsers. I tested on all browsers except IE until now, and for some reason this slide show does not work in IE. I can see that the demo (code pen) does in fact work in IE.

Would the additional CSS I added to handle the animations in Safari have caused IE to break? If anyone has an idea, it would be extremely appreciated!

```css
.slider {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.photo {
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
    -moz-animation: round 16s infinite;
    -ms-animation: round 16s infinite;
    -o-animation: round 16s infinite;
    animation: round 16s infinite;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes "round" {
    25% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes round {
 25% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "round" {
 25% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "round" {
 25% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes "round" {
 25% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}
.slider img:nth-child(20) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 76s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 76s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 76s;
 -o-animation-delay: 76s;
 animation-delay: 76s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(19) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 72s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 72s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 72s;
 -o-animation-delay: 72s;
 animation-delay: 72s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(18) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 68s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 68s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 68s;
 -o-animation-delay: 68s;
 animation-delay: 68s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(17) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 64s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 64s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 64s;
 -o-animation-delay: 64s;
 animation-delay: 64s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(16) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
 -o-animation-delay: 60s;
 animation-delay: 60s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(15) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 56s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 56s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 56s;
 -o-animation-delay: 56s;
 animation-delay: 56s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(14) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 52s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 52s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 52s;
 -o-animation-delay: 52s;
 animation-delay: 52s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(13) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 48s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 48s;
 -o-animation-delay: 48s;
 animation-delay: 48s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(12) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 44s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 44s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 44s;
 -o-animation-delay: 44s;
 animation-delay: 44s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(11) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 40s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 40s;
 -o-animation-delay: 40s;
 animation-delay: 40s;
}

slider img:nth-child(10) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
 -o-animation-delay: 36s;
 animation-delay: 36s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(9) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
 -o-animation-delay: 32s;
 animation-delay: 32s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(8) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 28s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 28s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 28s;
 -o-animation-delay: 28s;
 animation-delay: 28s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(7) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
 -o-animation-delay: 24s;
 animation-delay: 24s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 20s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 20s;
 -o-animation-delay: 20s;
 animation-delay: 20s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
 -o-animation-delay: 16s;
 animation-delay: 16s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
 -o-animation-delay: 12s;
 animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
 -o-animation-delay: 8s;
 animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
 -o-animation-delay: 4s;
 animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(1) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 -o-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8562523343_9bb49b7b7b.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your keyframe is only targeting webkit browsers. Try this:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

**Also your CSS**

```
.photo {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  -ms-animation: round 16s infinite;
  animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Forked Copy](http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/xwqLVV)

Comment: Trying this now. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm on a mac, but I'm booting up my Windows computer - if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: ah, i missed the keyframes

Comment: Ya you were right on track - I missed the CSS and only caught the keyframes at first, but then noticed the CSS too. I look forward to a day when possibly all these are just a single command.

Comment: Ok, so I actually had those suggested changes in my code and it did not work. I am updating the snippet now.

Comment: I think it's still missing the -ms-animation

Comment: Sorry took me a minute to update. I just finished now.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the -ms-animation
Is this what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Check it again.. I added the -ms-animation to the photo class.

Comment: It appears to be working in mine (Windows 7, IE 11), but in the link I still don't see the -ms-animation strangely... like it's not saving or the URL changed (though Codepen keeps the URL the same from what I remember, unless it's moved between private & public).

Comment: Ah, sorry @jhawes.. I updated the code in the snippet not the Codepen.

Comment: @EricBellDesigns My mistake. The forked version I have seems to be working (IE 11 - haven't tested back further). Cool slider too - very handy and lightweight for small image sections - great concept. http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/xwqLVV

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are using a webkit prefix? Add this:

```
-webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
animation: round 16s infinite;
```

Comment: Trying this now as well. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Added the -webkit-animation still no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution for css animation problems in IE.

I made a css image slider and it worked fine in all browser except IE. I tried all suggestion found on the web but no one worked. Finaly I stripped down the whole page and eventually found that it only worked in IE with an inline style in the header. (i.e. IE11 on windows 7, haven't tested the other IE versions yet)